# getting an object's public variable from another object (JAVA)

Tags: java

I have 2 classes: 'disability' and 'newDisability', i created a public variable in 'newDisability' which stores the name of the disability i'm creating but everytime i reference this from 'disability' i get the original value with which i defined the name of 'newDisability' instead of the new one i change it with.

```
public class disability extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    String disability ="";

    // Button that creates a newDisability JFrame
    private void newDisabilityActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                                  
        newDisability new= new newDisability();
        if (new.flag==true){
            disability = new.name;
        }
    }           
}
```

newDisability has a JTextField which takes the value and stores it into 'name' but i can't get this new value from 'disability'

```
Public class newDisability extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public String name= "ooo";
    public boolean flag=false;

    // The Button that creates the new disability and closes this window
    private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       name= (String) jTextField1.getText();
       flag=true;
       this.dispose();
    }
}
```

How can i get the new value i entered in my TextField instead of the one i defined initially ("ooo") at the start of the 'newDisability' class

Comment: What do you mean by "You can't get ..."? Is your program crashing? What exactly is wrong?

Comment: I can't see the relation between the two code sample. please post the main function

Comment: @Aify say i write "cancer" in the TextField of 'newDisability', when i press the save button of new disability it changes `name="ooo"` to `name="cancer"`, but i don't know the correct way to get this value from 'disability', check my code, when i'm calling new.name i'm only getting the old value("ooo") instead of "cancer"

Comment: Why don't you just use `disability = jTextField1.getText();`

Comment: You make a brand new `newDisability` every time the event fires; so it's always set to the default value when you read it.

Comment: @Gus yes, i don't know how to get my new 'name' value, i can only get my old one, there must be an easy way to get my object's value instead of the original class value of that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void newDisabilityActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                                  
    newDisability new= new newDisability();
    if (new.flag==true){
        disability = new.name;
    }
}
```

I think it is because the code triggers when you press the button to create the new Jframe and instantly you get the name when it has just been created so that could be why you are always getting the default value. You shoul get the name only AFTER the action of newDisability has been finished.

But it could help if you post the code where you add the listeners to the buttons.

Also should consider changing the name of your variable "new"

**Edit**

You could try the other way updating disability from newDisability

```
public class disability extends javax.swing.JFrame {
String disability ="";

// Button that creates a newDisability JFrame
private void newDisabilityActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                                  
    newDisability new= new newDisability(this);

}

 public void setName(String name){                                                  
    this.disability= name;

}
```

}

And the newDisability class

```
Public class newDisability extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public String name= "ooo";
public boolean flag=false;
private disability dis;

 public newDisability(disability d)
 {
   this.dis=d;
 }

 // The Button that creates the new disability and closes this window
 private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    name= (String) jTextField1.getText();
    flag=true;
    this.dis.setName(name);
    this.dispose();
 }
}
```

Comment: that's all my listener's code. I tried getting my new value of 'name' using a boolean flag as you can see in my code but it didn't work, after it creates the object it doesn't evalue the variable again, i assume i have to create a special method that re-checks the objects variable value but i don't know how

Comment: You could try passing the disability object to the newDisability in the constructor and then before disposing the Jframe of newDasability update the disability name. (It sounds weird)

Comment: it gives me the error `"constructor NewDissability in class NewDisability cannot be applied to given types;
required: disability
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght"`   in the  'NewDisabilityActionPerformed' method in 'disability' (where i create the 'NewDisability' object) and in the `new NewDisability().setVisible(true);` which is in the main method of 'NewDisability'

Comment: First I made a mistake, Your class is not named Disability with upper D is with lower d. Try to change that and be sure that in disability.newDisabilityActionPerformed you are calling "new newDisability(this)". I will change my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make two constructors in your `newDisability` class, the default no argument constructor and another one which accepts a new `name` and a `flag` value in parameter, so your code should be like this:

```
    public newDisability() {
         super();
    }
    public newDisability(String name, boolean flag) {
         this.name = name;
         this.flag = flag;
    }
```

And your call in the `createActionPerformed` method should be like this:

```
private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   newDisability new= new newDisability((String) jTextField1.getText(), true);
   this.dispose();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Or you can just EDIT your code to update the name each time:

```
Public class newDisability extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public String name= "ooo";
public boolean flag=false;
private newDisability disability = new newDisability();
// The Button that creates the new disability and closes this window
private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   disability.name= (String) jTextField1.getText();
   disability.flag=true;
   this.dispose();
}
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, the new `createActionPerformed` gives me a `';' expected  not a statement` error and in the recomendations it says `create method "newDisability(java.lang.String.boolean)"`.

Comment: @chsdk your `createActionPerformed()` method has a typo : `new= new`

Comment: @agapito take a look at my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting default values as you are creating new instance of `newDisability` in `newDisabilityActionPerformed()` method:

```
    newDisability new= new newDisability();
```

This creates new instance of newDisability with default value "ooo".

To use new value entered, you will have to pass the `newDisability` instance that has new value to `disability` class. That way you can access new value entered in text field.